# Samsung Galaxy s3 mini Wifi Connected but not working

Tags: wi-fi, samsung

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini and my Wi-Fi worked perfectly fine.
Later, I went on my phone and my Wi-Fi said it was connected but when I went on social media and stuff it said it wasn't connected. I tried everything. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First off try turning airplane mode off and on. That will often fix things. If that doesn't help, restart the phone. If that doesn't help, try [hard-reset.com/samsung-galaxy-s3-mini-hard-reset.html](http://hard-reset.com/samsung-galaxy-s3-mini-hard-reset.html) but make sure to backup the phone data first.